# Is it possible to deconstruct `self` when using class methods in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I want to clean up my code so it uses less `self.attribute` instances and is easier to read.

### Example of regular functionality:

```py
class Car:
    brand = None
    color = None
    model = None

    def __init__(self, color, brand, model):
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.model = model
    
    def print_car(self):
        print(f"This is a {self.color} {self.brand} manufactured in {self.model}"
```

```py
car_a = Car(color='red', brand='audi', model=2001)
car_a.print_car()
# output: This is a red audi manufactured in 2001
```

### How I would like to change it:

I would like to deconstruct the `self` argument on `print_car` so it would be a bit cleaner, but achieve the same functionality.something like this:

```py
def print_car({color, brand, model}):
    print(f"This is a {color} {brand} manufactured in {model}"
```

Is that possible? Common? It's mainly just cleaner code but maybe it's not a good approach?

Comment: This won't remove the specific boilerplate you're asking about, but the `attrs` library will shorten these sort of classes considerably: https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html

Comment: Python does not have destructuring, only unpacking of iterables. Perhaps you are looking for ``vars(self)`` to get the attributes of ``self``? This would allow ``"This is a {color} {brand} manufactured in {model}".format(**vars(self))``.

Comment: Can the same code be achieved with `f` string without referencing `self` 3 times in each bracket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the builtin function `vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to get the attributes of most instances as a dictionary. This allows to invoke callables with the attributes, e.g. by using `**`-unpacking to use them as keyword arguments:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color=None, brand=None, model=None):
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.model = model

    def print_car(self):
        print(
           "This is a {color} {brand} manufactured in {model}".format(
               **vars(self)  # get and unpack attributes to keyword arguments
        ))
```

This is not common usage in methods, though it does have its uses. Classes have many capabilities that conflict with explicit destructuring – most importantly subclassing and [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) making attributes not strictly defined.

However, classes solely intended to hold a specific set of attributes can be safely destructured. For example, [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) directly support converting instances to [mappings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) and [sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.astuple). This allows to destructure attributes by name or order.

---

If destructuring is needed often, it can be automatised using decorators. A simple decorator to destructure the first argument looks like this:

```py
def destruct(method):
    """Mark a method to destructure ``self`` into its arguments"""
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, **kwargs):
        return method(**vars(self), **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

It can be applied like other method decorators, e.g. `classmethod`, directly in the `class` definition. The method then takes each attribute as a separate argument, instead of the single `self` argument.

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color=None, brand=None, model=None):
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.model = model

    @destruct
    def print_car(color, brand, model):
        print(f"This is a {color} {brand} manufactured in {model}")


Car(color='red', brand='audi', model=2001).print_car()
# This is a red audi manufactured in 2001
```

Note that `destruct` is a demonstrator. For example, `vars` does not work for classes using `__slots__` – some fallbacks can be used if needed or inspecting the class' `__annotations__`. Also, the method does not support positional arguments anymore – inspecting the signature or otherwise normalising arguments would allow this.